# Бесплатное api биржевых курсов валют

Tags: поиск-api

Может кто-нибудь знает. Бывает ли бесплатное API для получение биржевых курсов валют? Хотелось бы получать с данные ММВБ, частота запросов хотя бы раз в 20-30 минут.
Нужно для open-source проекта.
Есть платные API с бесплатный, начальный тариф, но число запросов очень скудное.

Comment: Запасайтесь ip-шниками. в чем проблема то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На Финаме можно очень часто получать данные даже без подписок. Вот статья https://habr.com/ru/post/332700/ на Хабре с источниками. Сам пробовал, но пока отошёл от этой темы.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Вот бесплатный [API для получения курсов валют в Украине](https://github.com/pavlovich-app/KursToday-API)

Можно получить курс валют в обменниках и банках Украины.

Курс валют предоставляет сайт [rate.in.ua](https://rate.in.ua)